# Photoshop image fading and background effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, mask

I believe it's easy to do, but I am missing some details. Somehow, my results are not what I'd wanted them to look like.

- How to draw illustrational lines? (Think of the lines from [Windows Vista login screen](http://www.google.fi/search?q=%22windows%20vista%22%20login&tbm=isch), for example.)
- … and how to crossfade the created image with another image?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: fade and lines example]

Other example of lines I'd like to draw (and later fade over some image):

[image: lines example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fade is best done using masking.
(The example you gave actually has some poor cloning in it, but that's irrelevant)

Basically:
1) Create a new layer mask

2) Select the gradient tool (G)

3) Drag out your gradient, make sure it's the "black to transparent" gradient.

Here's an image:
[image]

As for the line, I recommend just using the pen tool. If you want your lines to "fade out" just use masking! It looks like you're doing a great job already :]