# Background gradient style like Netflix hero image on homepage

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I am wondering if anyone could provide some advice on how to create a background hero image like Netflix (gradient dark starting from the left side of the image) has on their homepage. What I am struggling with is to create a similar effect in photoshop.

Any tips?

Screenshot examples[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you think you could provide a screenshot, or an example image.  I have no idea what a "background hero image like Netflix" is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Photoshop image fading and background effect](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/photoshop-image-fading-and-background-effect)

Answer (score 2):

Grab the **Gradient Tool**

Select the **Black to Transparent** gradient from the **Control Bar**
[image]

Add a new layer above your photo and click-drag from the left edge to create the gradient.

[image]